# How to display a double value in a JLabel

Tags: java

I have a Jlabel called Basic Salary and a JtextField called NoOfWorkingDays I need to calculate Net Salary  for the no of Days a employee worked, So my code is like this,

```
float Sal=Float.parseFloat(lblSalary.getText());
float days=Float.parseFloat(txtNoofworking.getText());
float tot;
tot = (float) ((Sal/30.0)*days);
lblNetSal.setText(tot);
```

this code not giving the answer So Show me the mistake I have done here or Please show me the correct way of doing this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Convert float `tot` to `String`

```
tot = (float) ((Sal/30.0)*days);
String s = Float.toString(tot);
lblNetSal.setText(s);
```